# How do I design this?

Tags: php, mysql

So; I`m a PHP noob and I'm trying to get a website to work, as a fun side-project. I currently have a database with lyrics, and who sung those lyrics etc. Now I echo these onto LYRICS.PHP with the following code:

Functions.php

```
function getLyric() {
(int)$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE id = ".$id."") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <h1><?= $row['title']; ?> lyrics</h1>
    <h2><?= $row['author']; ?></h2>

    <pre><?= $row['lyrics']; ?></pre>
    <?php }     
}
```

Lyrics.php?id=1

```
<?php getLyric(); ?>
```

Which works, but how do I display the singer and name of the song in the [title] tag of the page? (currently it's just plain html). With how I design it right now I don't think that is possible right?

Comment: @AndrewBarrett How so? The variable is cast to an integer. 'Sfar as I can see numbers are perfectly safe. Not saying that this code is good, mind, but I don't see the injection hole.

Comment: So that you have a better chance of getting your question answered, good to go for a more specific question title.

Comment: @Kolink: have you actually tested that? `(int)$x = '123test'; var_dump($x);` dumps the full string, not an integer.

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, of course. My bad. I was thinking of `$id = (int)$_GET['id']`. Although personally I'd use `addslashes` at the very least anyway and put the value in quotes in the query and all that other good stuff.

Comment: Okay, deleted my unclear previous comments, so @user1333327, you do have a SQL injection attack in your code so watch out!

Comment: There's a PHP function called `intval()` which converts a string to an int. It's usually what I use for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're outputting the HTML. If you are using inline HTML in `lyrics.php`, then you can do something like:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<title><?php echo getTitle(); ?></title>
...
```

If you are echoing a string of HTML, then you can do something like:

```
echo "<title>" . getTitle() . "</title>"
```

Obviously you need to make the `getTitle` function first.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you could do. It's not too pretty and it absolutely could be streamlined, but it should get what you want done.

### HTML

Lyrics.php?id=1

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php getTitle(); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php getLyric(); ?>
</body>
```

### PHP

```
function getLyric() {
(int)$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE id = ".$id."") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <h1><?= $row['title']; ?> lyrics</h1>
    <h2><?= $row['author']; ?></h2>

    <pre><?= $row['lyrics']; ?></pre>
    <?php }     
}

function getTitle() {
(int)$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE id = ".$id."") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?><?= $row['title']; ?> by <?= $row['author']; ?><?php } ?>   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make your function to return an array or object from the result of that query, then output the array items where you want instead of having your function generating the markup..
also consider some filtering to the value you pass to GET variable